# How to trigger jQuery every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have a problem regarding my Javascript code: i want my code to load every second but that won't work here's my Javascript:

```
$('#search_text').setInterval(function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    if(search != '')
    {
        load_data(search);
    }
    else
    {
        load_data();
    }
}, 100);
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with a console.log ? `100` is 100ms thus 0.1s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this pointer here is not actually referring to the search-text element
You might have to try below

```
$('#search_text').setInterval(function(){
    var search = $('#search_text').val();
    if(search != '')
    {
        load_data(search);
    }
    else
    {
        load_data();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Input boxes dont have `setInterval` method. Try the following:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var search = $('#search_text').val();
  if(search != '') {
    load_data(search);
  } else {
    load_data();
  }
}, 1000);
```